# Lift of a continuous map $f:Y\to X$ to a covering space $Z$ given that loops in $Y$ lift to loops in $Z$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Suppose $X, Y$, and $Z$ are topological spaces. If necessary, you may assume that they are nice (manifolds). I am looking for the following result to be true even without this assumption however, so any comments to that effect would also be appreciated.

Let $p:Z\to X$ be a covering map. Let $f:Y\to X$ be a continuous map. Let $x_0\in X$, $y_0\in Y$, $z_0\in Z$ be such that $f(y_0)=x_0=p(z_0)$. Assume that for each loop $\gamma$ at $y_0$ in $Y$, there is a loop $\tilde{\gamma}$ at $z_0$ in $Z$ such that $f\circ \gamma$ is homotopic to $p\circ \tilde{\gamma}$ in $X$ with endpoints both fixed at $x_0$ by the homotopy.

Prove that $f$ lifts to a continuous map $\tilde{f}:Y\to Z$ with $\tilde{f}(y_0)=z_0$.

Overall, it is entirely unclear to me why such a lift should even exist. The standard results concerning relations between fundamental groups are not something that I wish to employ since there are no restrictions on the spaces, nor do I think this would even be helpful. Any comments at all would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you do not want to use fundamental groups, but this does not make sense.

In terms of fundamental groups, your condition means that $f_*(\pi_1(Y,y_0)) \subset p_*(\pi_1(Z,z_0))$. It is a well-known theorem that for $Y$ path-connected and locally path-connected this condition is equivalent to the existence of a lift of $f$. See for example Proposition 1.33 in Hatcher's "Algebraic Topology". Hatcher also gives an example showing that the local path-connectedness assumption cannot be omitted.

You can of course copy Hatcher's (fairly short) proof without mentioning fundamental groups, but what would be the benefit?